# Which is best way to clear cache when my site opens in browser?

Tags: php, caching

i have put this code in my index.php i need to put this code in all my page or just this code works in index page ?

```
<?php
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
?>
```

Comment: Further there is no way to force a browsers _cache_ to be cleared, that is under client side control only.

Comment: What you _can_ do is prevent objects you served to be cached in the first place, for example by sending correct headers. Whether you have to do that only in a single file or multiple ones obviously depends on your code, your application, whatever. We may be good, but we are not that good that we can somehow magically _guess_ your situation.